# How can I find all swift system modules I can import?

Tags: xcode, swift, import, module, frameworks

Is there anything in swift that works like frameworks list in Xcode while using Obj-C? I want to know what modules I can use by default. e.g.. CoreData, CoreImage, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Method - 1**

To use any Objective-C Framework in Swift, you need to create 'Bridging-header.h" file and import your framework there to use anywhere in your swift project.

[To add Bridging header in Swift Project](http://www.learnswiftonline.com/getting-started/adding-swift-bridging-header/)

**Method - 2**

You can direct import any framework.

```
E.g. import CoreData
```

The main problem is that Xcode doesn't provide "AutoComplete" option for "import" statement so that's the problem as of now.

Reference: [Import Framework in Swift Project, Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24057756/import-framework-in-swift-project-xcode-6-0-beta)

Edited:

Most Popular List of Swift Modules which you can get from Xcode:

https://github.com/andelf/Defines-Swift

Comment: Thank you for your answer Sohil. But is there any way to disclose every module other than modules I do know. Or where on earth are those modules placed?

Comment: @Obj-Steve Yes, there is! Please check the edited answer

Comment: Yeah, that's plenty of them, if not all of them. Thanks a lot Sohil. :D