# Importing pure Swift custom framework into other Swift project

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, frameworks

Let's, I have a custom Swift `Cocoa Touch framework`, `MyLog`, which has a simple function called `printLog()`. I have another Swift project named `HelloWorld` in different workspace/location. Now I need to import the custom framework `MyLog` into project `HelloWorld`, so that I can call `MyLog.printLog()`.

```
Project -> Targets -> Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries
```

does not show my custom library in the list. Moreover I don't just want to link my custom library, rather I want to import separately as independent library so that running changes in `MyLog` wont reflect in `HelloWorld`.

> NB: Similar things I do in Android with adding `custom_library.jar` in
>   lib.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally I got the solution with below steps,

## Steps

1. Mark your custom `MyLog` project as `Framework` when creating
2. Implement `func printLog` and build the project (successful build will create a `/Product/MyLog.framework` file)
3. Copy the `/Product/Mylog.framework` file into `HelloWorld` project directory using Finder
4. Follow, `HelloWorld Project -> Targets -> Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries -> + -> Add Other` (select `MyLog.framework` from `HelloWorld/` directory)
5. Follow, `HelloWorld Project -> Targets -> Build Phases -> Embed Frameworks -> + -> Other` (select `MyLog.framework` from `HelloWorld/` directory)
6. Build `HelloWorld` and enjoy!

#### Update 1

1. If you don't find path,
   `HelloWorld Project -> Targets -> Build Phases -> Embed Frameworks` please check, `HelloWorld Project -> Targets -> General -> Embedded Binaries` in the later versions of xcode, which will do the same thing step-5 does.

Comment: I dont see step 5 in project ... :(

Comment: @Alix this was for previous Xcode version, you will get `Embedded Binaries` under general tab, which will do the same. Reference: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37690368/1084174

Comment: my case is that framework is being generate in same workspace. so I dont need to put anything in the bridging-header.h. I can just import it, correct ?

Comment: that worked but I have one objc lib, what would be correct place to add it as bridging header not able to find it ? thanks a lot for updating the answer.

Comment: This pointed me to the right direction. I was able to solve the problem I was having. Kudos

Answer (score 1):

add the frameworks to "Embedded Binaries" (Target > General > Embedded Binaries) then run