# Xcode doesnt have Embed Frameworks section

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, xcode7

I'm having a problem. I'm trying to implement Amazon frameworks in my ios xcode project and I also need to add them in Build Phases > Embed Frameworks section. But there is no option in my xcode window. Here is the screenshot

[image]

How is this possible. The problem remains even if I create new project.

Comment: In general tab check there

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Hello in your general Tab with your target selected check for section named

[image]

> Embedded Binaries

I hope this help you

Comment: This doesn't seem to lead to "Embedded Binaries" in Xcode 8.2.1: [proof](http://imgur.com/a/WfeK9). I can't seem to find it anywhere and searching with the "Help" option also returns nothing.

Comment: Hello @Mathews24 you must have selected your target app, and there is still in Xcode 8.2.1 if you want i can provide new ScreenShot with Xcode 8.2.1

Comment: It is simply a C++ code. Besides [simply selecting the project in the left panel](http://imgur.com/a/8Aao1), do you mean anything else by "selecting the target app"?

Comment: Hello @Mathews24 I had been very busy with a lot of work, but here is your image explaining how its works and another image from myself finishing the explanation I hope this helps you and everybody else, http://imgur.com/a/0MYbD best regards

Comment: So the Embedded Frameworks section is now called Embedded Binaries?

Answer (score 12):

Another reason Embedded Binaries tab doesn't show up in Xcode is if you're in a command line project instead of a cocoa project and you're targeting Mac OS X.

Answer (score 6):

You can create it on Build Phases tab!

Just click in the "+" icon and select "New Copy Files Phase". After that, rename the item created to "Embed Frameworks" and set the "Destination" field to "Frameworks".

Answer (score 1):

You can tap the `General` tab to see those sections.

As an aside, using CocoaPods or Fabric will make that integration easier on you.