# I cannot get Xcode to properly use the FacebookLogin framework after installing the pods

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, facebook-login

I am trying to implement Facebook Login to my app. It appears to install fine, but I cannot import ANY of the modules that I installed, and all of the frameworks in pods/frameworks are RED.

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling so many times, but its basically as if the frameworks don't exist. How on earth can I solve this? I've deleted derived data, cleaned the project, cleaned the build folder, reinstalled the FB pods..... I'm at a loss!

Comment: are you opening the project or workspace?

Comment: Definitely the workspace

Comment: did it solve your problem?..

Comment: No. I was already using the workspace.

Comment: which pod you installing?

Comment: pod 'FacebookCore'
pod 'FacebookLogin'

Comment: check this it might help you?.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24057756/import-framework-in-swift-project-xcode