# add facebook and google login in custom framework in swift

Tags: swift, xcode, facebook

i am working on different projects. where all projects need facebook and google SDK integration.

The are two way's which i can adopt:

1. integrate fb and google sdk's in all projects

**OR**

2. create a common project (cocoa framework) and just add that framework in all projects. common logic

I want to use 2nd approach and now i have a framework project with pod file. How can i add this framework into my App because there is .xcworkspace file which does not add like framework.

Comment: If you want to add framework into your app then refer this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24057756/import-framework-in-swift-project-xcode

If you want to add your custom framework in cocoapod and use this pod commonly then follow this links :
https://medium.com/flawless-app-stories/create-your-own-cocoapods-library-da589d5cd270

Second link :
https://www.raywenderlich.com/5823-how-to-create-a-cocoapod-in-swift

Comment: just want to add facebook and google login in custom framework in swift

Comment: @AR did you done that ?